# How to run cygwin's startxwin from bashrc?

Tags: bash, cygwin, x11, xterm

I use cygwin occasionally, where I start a mintty.exe from Windows 7, and then run the following command to start XWindows and an xterm:

```
/bin/run.exe /usr/bin/bash.exe -l -c /usr/bin/startxwin.exe &
```

I tried to automate this xterm creation, by entering the following stanza at the end of my ~/.bashrc:

```
if [ `ps -ef | grep XWin | wc -l` -lt 1 ] ; then 
    echo "will start Xwin"
    /bin/run.exe /usr/bin/bash.exe -l -c /usr/bin/startxwin.exe 
    sleep 300
fi
```

However, XWin is not starting, and the following error is printed:

```
Usage: /usr/bin/grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Try `/usr/bin/grep --help' for more information.
bash: [: too many arguments
```

Can you suggest a way to start an xterm instance from Windows?

Notes:

- I read the Cygwin FAQ and Googled for an answer.
- Environment:
  Windows 7 
  CYGWIN_NT-6.1-WOW64 1.7.33-2(0.280/5/3) i686 Cygwin

### Edit

Based on @EtanReisner and @pjh comments, I changed the startxwin stanza to the following, which is working:

```
if ( ! pgrep XWin ) > /dev/null ; then 
    echo "will start Xwin"
    /bin/run.exe /usr/bin/bash.exe -l -c /usr/bin/startxwin.exe 
fi
```

Comment: `grep` is complaining about something there. That's causing `test`/`[` to get too many arguments and complain itself. You need to figure out why `grep` is complaining. (You might also want to see if you have `pgrep` instead of that pipeline.)

Comment: A common cause of problems with Bash scripts under Cygwin is that Windows (CR-LF) line endings are added by accident (though I can't see how that would cause this problem).   One way to debug the problem is to put `set -o xtrace` before the code that is failing.  The code itself is a good example of [Useless Use of Wc -l](http://www.smallo.ruhr.de/award.html#wc).  One way to fix it is: `if ! ps -ef | grep -q XWin ; then ...`.  As @EtanReisner wrote, it would be even better to use 'pgrep' if it is available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @EtanReisner and @pjh comments, I changed the startxwin stanza to the following, which is working:

```
if ( ! pgrep XWin ) > /dev/null ; then 
    echo "will start Xwin"
    /bin/run.exe /usr/bin/bash.exe -l -c /usr/bin/startxwin.exe 
fi
```